# unicode chars with wikipedia search in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, wikipedia

I pass a PHP string to wikipedia search page in order to retrieve part of the definition.
Everythin works fine, except unicode chars which appear in the **\u...** form. Here is an example to explain myself better. As you can see, the phonetic transcription of the name is not readable:

> Henrik Ibsen, Henrik Ibsen \u02c8h\u025bn\u027eik \u02c8ips\u0259n
>   (Skien, 20 marzo 1828 - Oslo, 23 maggio 1906) è stato uno scrittore,
>   drammaturgo, poeta e regista teatrale norvegese.

The code I use to get the snippet from Wikipedia is this:

```
$word = $_GET["word"];
$html = file_get_contents('https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.$word);
$utf8html = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $html), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

The last line of my code does not solve the problem.
Do you know how to get a clean text which is entirely readable?

Comment: Just use `json_decode`: `$utf8html = json_decode('"'.$html.'"');` Working [eval](https://eval.in/488883).

Comment: This solution does not work for me, probably because my `$html` variable is not a simple text string - it's the output of `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the Wikipedia search API is JSON. Don't try to scrape bits out of it and parse string literal escapes yourself, that way madness lies. Just use a readily available JSON parser.

Also, you need to URL-escape the word when you add it into a query string, otherwise any searches for words with URL-special characters in will fail.

In summary:

```
$word = $_GET['word'];
$url = 'https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.urlencode($word);
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

$matching_titles_array = $response[1];
$matching_summaries_array = $response[2];
$matching_urls = $response[3];
...etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You got some errors in your regex string, try using:

```
<?php
 $str = "Henrik Ibsen, Henrik Ibsen \u02c8h\u025bn\u027eik \u02c8ips\u0259n(Skien, 20 marzo 1828 - Oslo, 23 maggio 1906) è stato uno scrittore, drammaturgo, poeta e regista teatrale norvegese.";
 $utf8html = preg_replace('@\\\U([0-9A-F]{4})@i', "&#x\\1", $str);
 echo $utf8html;
```

Comment: There are some problems here, you won't get the results you expect here for (a) other backslash escapes like `\"` or `\n`; (b) characters above U+00FFFF; (c) any `\u` sequence followed by a literal character in the range `[0-9A-Fa-f]` (due to missing character reference semicolon terminator).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer posted by bobince is certainly more effective than my previous procedure, which aimed at scraping and pruning bit by bit what I needed. Just to show you how I was doing it, here is my previous code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.$s);
$decoded = preg_replace('@\\\U([0-9A-F]{4})@i', "&#x\\1", $html);
$par = array("[", "]");
$def_no_par = str_replace($par, "", $decoded);
$def_no_vir = str_replace("\"\",", "", $def_no_par);
$def_cap = str_replace("\",", "\",<br>", $def_no_vir);
$def_pulita = str_replace("\"", "", $def_cap);
$def_clean = str_replace(".,", ".", $def_pulita);
$definizione = str_replace("$s,", "", $def_clean);
$out = str_replace("\\", "\"", $definizione);
```

As you can see, removing parts of the output to make it more readable was quite tiresome (and not completely successful).
Using the JSON approach makes everything more linear. Here is my new workaround:

```
$search = 'https://it.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search='.urlencode($s);
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($search));
$matching_titles_array = $response[1];
$matching_summaries_array = $response[2];
$matching_urls = $response[3];

echo '<h3><div align="center"><font color=" #A3A375">'.$titolo.'</font></div></h3><br><br>';
foreach($response[1] as $t) {
    echo '<font color="#5C85D6"><b>'.$t.'</b></font><br><br>';
}
foreach($response[2] as $s) {
    echo $s.'<br><br>';
}
foreach($response[3] as $l) {
$link = preg_replace('!(((f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $l);
    echo $link.'<br><br>';
}
```

The advantage is that now I can manipulate the arrays as I wish.
You can see it in action [here](http://trovawiki.altervista.org/oggi.php):